# mturk select element with conditional logic

Tags: java, html, forms, mturk

I am trying to program a basic conditional logic into an mTurk HIT task. I want to have two dropdown menus, with the options in the second dropdown menu conditional on the option selected in the first.

For example, if the first menu was:

```
<select name="qualificationType" required>
            <option value="">High School</option>
            <option value="">Some College</option>
            <option value="">Associate Degree</option>
            <option value="">Bachelor's Degree</option>
            <option value="">Professional Degree</option>
            <option value="">Master's Degree</option>
            <option value="">Doctorate Degree</option>        
        </select>
```

I would want several dropdown options based on the selection in the first. I know how to make the other dropdown menus, but am unsure of how to add the logical connection. Something like a basic ifelse would work, but am unable to find a solution in HTML.